# How to create an XML file using TXML Document in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I have used the following code to create the XML Document :

```
procedure TForm1.btnCreateXMLClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
   rootName:string;
  childName:string;
  attrChild:string;
   iXml: IDOMDocument;
  iRoot, iNode, iNode2, iChild, iAttribute: IDOMNode;
begin
  XMLDoc.Active:=false;
   XMLDoc.XML.Text:='';
   XMLDoc.Active:=true;
    XMLDoc.FileName:='C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\New Text Document.xml';
     iXml := XmlDoc.DOMDocument;
   //iRoot:=iXml.documentElement(iXml.createElement('xml'));
    iRoot := iXml.appendChild(iXml.createElement ('xml'));
     // node "test"
     iNode := iRoot.appendChild (iXml.createElement ('test'));
      iNode.appendChild (iXml.createElement ('test2'));
   iChild := iNode.appendChild (iXml.createElement ('test3'));
    iChild.appendChild (iXml.createTextNode('simple value'));
     iNode.insertBefore (iXml.createElement ('test4'), iChild);

   // node replication
     iNode2 := iNode.cloneNode (True);
  iRoot.appendChild (iNode2);

    // add an attribute
      iAttribute := iXml.createAttribute ('color');
        iAttribute.nodeValue := 'red';
      iNode2.attributes.setNamedItem (iAttribute);

    // show XML in memo
      memXMLOutput.Lines.Text:=FormatXMLData(XMLDoc.XML.Text);
   end;
```

I get the output in memXMLOutput but the XML document does not show the output when seen in Notepad ot IE. where is the problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Congratulations, you have posted the ten thousandth question in the Delphi tag.

Comment: Huh! +1 for the ten thousandth Delphi question!

Comment: YIPEE!!!! i am a master of the world

Comment: unobvious get, should post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666666/ next time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove this:

```
XMLDoc.FileName:='C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\New Text Document.xml';
```

and add something like this after the code is done creating the XML document:

```
XMLDoc.SaveToFile('C:\Documents and Settings\a\Desktop\New Text Document.xml');
```