# Connecting ad-hoc network from android devices

Tags: android, adhoc

I was trying to connect an ad-hoc network from Nexus S. However I realized the unpleasant news that Android does not support ad-hoc networking. After a quite amount of research, I found a work around which is:

a) Root the device and
b) Copy wpa_supplicant to system bin.

I'm totally unsure how much successful that would be. Being fairly apprehensive to further this method, I returned back to research and, unfortunately, ended up in vain.

Has anyone dealt this before? Is there any fix for ad-hoc networking in Android?

Answer (score 1):

While Adnroid (at least 2.3) does not have interface for setting up Ad-hoc or Master modes, sometimes (like on my SE Xperia X10) you can just use iwconfig (need to be copied to device manually) and set it to Ad-hoc mode.

I use it sometimes, having scripts that ad-hoc mode on and off (there is even dhcp server configured on the device)

Answer (score -1):

Well, I am facing the problem too. and was googling around and could not find anything worth sharing with you. Just a work around, Use [ConnectifyME](http://www.connectify.me/) to create an AP in your PC and then you can use that AP (can say virtual AP) to share internet on your android device.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Well, I did create a hotspot to route all requests coming from the Android device to the targeted network.

Answer (score -1):

There is a GUI program called Virtual router that is open source program and could be used to create WiFi, it uses virtual Wi-Fi feature in Windows 7.

For more description have a look at my post:
http://algorithmsea.blogspot.in/2012/12/ad-hoc-network-from-android-devices-i.html

Answer (score -2):

adhoc isn't supported in android os but typing 2 lines DOS commands should solve the problem.

I tested this and it works.. type these 2 lines on DOS COMMAND PROMPT

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=NAME key=PASSWORD 
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I found this here : For Android users:Internet via adhoc is working without any app! : http://androiditnow.blogspot.com/2012/09/for-android-usersinternet-via-adhoc-is.html#.UXV0bUqlrGI